# Dynamic code template in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

My application contains a lot of objects that implement an interface.

Those objects all have the same functions, and what mainly depends between them is the number of class variables and their type.

I think about creating a general template that could be filled with only a few parameters (name of the class, name of each variable and its type).

Here is a (really) simple example (having two parameters ):

```
    public class myClass implements anotherClass {

    private int a;
    /** Image reference */
    private int myInt;    

    /** Security elements */
    private String myString;

    public myClass() {
    }


    public myObj getValueObject() {
        myObj value = new myObj();

        value.setmyInt(myInt);
        value.setmyString(myString);

        return value;
    }    

    public String getmyInt() {
        return myInt;
    }

    public void setmyInt(String myInt) {
        this.myString = myString;
        if (a == 10) {
            a =0;
        }
    }    

    public String getmyString() {
        return myInt;
    }

    public void setmyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
        if (a == 10) {
            a =0;
        }
    }    

    public int doIt() {
        int number = 0;
        number = number + toNumber(myInt);
        number = number + toNumber(myString);
        return number ;
    }    

}
```

As I said, the only difference between classes is the number, name and type of the variables.

I looked at code templates in Eclipse, but it seems to be simple (but efficient) string replacement.
I would like a bit more, as it needs to write more or less code depending on the number of input variables.

I could hard code something in Java with string replacement by myself, but I wonder is there is not a tool somewhere that could help me in my task.

I would feed it with prototypes of my methods and my inputs variables.

Any hint is appreciated, 
Thanks !

Comment: I juts found JDynamiTe that looks like what I want . http://jdynamite.sourceforge.net/doc/jdynamite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [JDynamiTe](http://jdynamite.sourceforge.net/doc/jdynamite.html) that does what I want.

I use it to dynamically generate my files given lists of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of templating and code generation libraries. One of the most prevalent is [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/). A number of Eclipse projects use [JET](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Though it is late, i thought it might help others. Try using [Fastcode](http://3pintech.com/products/fast-code/templates.htm#typesofsnippets) Plugin which has templates which helps you to generate this kind of code.